# How to create Radio player based on Gnome MPlayer?

Tags: gnome, application-development, mplayer

I want to make a radio player based on Gnome MPlayer, but just for one radio station, some like a native radio application.
I don't know if I have permission to modify MPlayer, but since is open source...
An if I have permission to mofify it, where do i find the containing folder of it.
This is what I want to create http://tixel.ro/images/onefm.png

Comment: You don't need to modify Mplayer at all. Just write your own GUI shell around it. Much like SMplayer and Gnome-Mplayer are developed. Just download the sources of the packages using `apt-get source` and follow the regular Ubuntu/Debian application development how-to's. You've got several choices for the GUI front-end. Python with Qt, native Gnome/C or GTK/Vala, etc. etc. Make your question a bit more narrow after some research, that would give a lot more useful answers.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer, the app i whanted to create is now on development here https://github.com/micku7zu/QtOneFM

Answer (score 1):

as gertvdijk said, you dont need to modify mplayer, but to answer the question 'where do i find the containing folder of it'

```
    which mplayer
```

that will show you where mplayer is installed, or atleast give you a symlink to the installation path. and to find out if its a symlink or not

```
    file /usr/bin/mplayer
```

that will tell you what kind of file it is and if its a symlink, it will also tell you what its linking too.

Comment: `which` shows where the binary is ... perhaps using `where mplayer` would be more appropriate? Or using `dpkg -L mplayer` to list all of the installed files?